# express - getting path of parrent router?

Tags: node.js, express

Lets say I want to have 2 different instances in "subfolders" in the url. In app js I have it defined like this:

```
var routes = require('./routes/index');

app.use('/myapp1', routes);
app.use('/myapp2', routes);
```

The inner routing would be the same.

But still in the router I want to "get" the path defined in the **app.use** - eg.: myapp1, myapp2

How do I get this in the router?

From routes/index.js:

```
router.use(/\/.*/, function (req, res, next) {
  // want to see "myapp1/myapp2" without the *sub* path defined in this particular router eg.: /products /user etc.
  next();
});
```

Comment: What's wrong with looking inside the `req` object to get the path?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use the [`req.baseUrl`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.baseUrl) property.

Example:

```
routes.get('/1', function(req, res) {
  res.send([
    req.baseUrl,
    req.path,
    req.baseUrl + req.path,
  ].join('\n'));
});

app.use('/api', routes);
```

Making an HTTP request to `/api/1` would print:

```
/api
/1
/api/1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    req.appInstance = (req.url.indexOf('/app2/') == 0) ? 2 : 1; 
    next();
});

app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.redirect('/app1/user');
});

router.get('/user', function(req, res, next) {
    res.send(req.url +' on app' + req.appInstance);
});

app.use('/app1', router);
app.use('/app2', router);

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```